# Exclude Javascript function within a (TFS) build

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, tfs

Hello I got a question regarding including or excluding specific contents of my JS file within my C# project. I developed a new JS functions which is still under development and it is based in my *library.js* file. Within C# you can set build flags in order to say which sections should be included whenever a build is running. FYI I am using TFS to build.

Now I was wondering is there a way within Visual Studio or TFS or some other mechanisme where I can say that a particular piece of code within my *library.js* file should not be included within my build? Like I can do with build flags within my C# code.

Perhaps I can use some prebuild steps or trying to come up with some JS code which check the current active buildflags?

Anyone have any ideas? I know that removing the code will solve it but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you aware of branching in TFS? You can create a branch to work on a specific feature, without impacting the developers working on the "main" or "trunk". Once you have finished implementing your code, you merge it back into the trunk - that way the trunk only contains working code.

Comment: mmm good one! I might check that out. I was not aware of this whole branching concept.

Answer (score 0):

On TFS side, TFS build has the capability to map or cloak file, but doesn't has the feature to exclude a piece of code within a file. An easy way from TFS side is to use TFS branch to develop your own feature.

[image]